# Does a list stay ordered in .NET?

Tags: .net, list, generics

I can't find an answer to the following "simple" question:

If I order elements of a list and put the whole thing into a new list, like

```
var newList = new List<IMyElement>(myElements.OrderBy(x => x.AnyProperty));
```

Can I be sure, the elements in newList are still ordered by AnyProperty at access time?

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you create the list it will keep the sorting you gave it for the existing items. Any new items added with `.Add(` later will not be automatically sorted.

If you want new items that are added later to be automaticly sorted you will need to use a [sorted collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67(v=vs.110).aspx) type

Comment: Note that when you use .Add it will add the new item to the end of the list.  You can also use [.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411(v=vs.110).aspx) to insert a new item at a specific position.